# Block automated request to page

Tags: php, csrf

I've developed a site with basic search function. The site accepts input in GET params and the site is hosted on a shared hosting server. **Thus there are limits on SQL execution**.
My goal is to stop [*or at least lower the chance*] of processing automated search query so the site does not reach the SQL limit for bogus search queries where there is no real user.To prevent this I've used CSRF in the landing page from where search is initiated.

What else can I try to make sure that the search is performed only for real users and not for automated/bot search. *I've thought of CAPTCHAs but asking to confirm CAPTCHA for every search query will make it really worse.*

Comment: **asking to confirm CAPTCHA for every search query will make it really worse** --- why ?

Comment: @KenLee it'll help with avoiding bots, but will also damage the user experience.

Comment: Depending on the amount of data - you could use a redis or memcached. This will increase performance drastically. You can do a warming or just cache once received results from the database. So you check for a cache hit, and when not call the database and cache it.

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to the eternal dichotomy between useability and security. ;)

Many of the measures that are used to detect and block bots, also impact usability (such as the extra steps required by opaque captchas). None of which solve the bot problem 100% either (ala [captcha farms](https://www.netacea.com/blog/what-are-captcha-farms/)).

The trick is to use a reasonable mix of controls, and to try hard not to impact the user experience as much as possible.

A good combination that I have used with success to protect high-cost functions on high-volume sites is:

- CSRF: this is a good basic measure in itself to stop blind script
  submission, but won't slow down or stop a sophisticated attacker at
  all;
- response caching: search engines tend to get used for the same thing
  repeatedly, so by caching the answers to common searches, you avoid
  making the SQL request altogether (which avoids the resource
  consumption, and also improves regular usage too);
- source throttling: track the source IP and restrict the number of
  operations within a reasonable window (not rejecting any outside
  this, just queueing them and so throttling the volume to a reasonable
  level); and
- transparent captcha: something like Google's [CAPTCHAv3](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/v3) in
  transparent mode will help you drop a lot of the automated requests,
  without impacting the user experience.

Answer (score 0):

You could also look at developing your search function to search an XML file instead of via the database. This would enable you to search as many times as you like without any issues.